# bidirectional Javascript window.postMessage - dispatch order issue

Tags: javascript, iframe, xss, postmessage

`postMessage` can be used to send messages between windows, typically from an iframe to the parent or the parent to an iframe.

`postMessage` sends data only in one direction and is out-of-line - unlike function calls, which return values from the call and are executed in-line (the latter is a condition for the former).

In order to sent information back to the "caller", the "callee" has to do its own `postMessage`.

Now let's assume that I want to test if a suited listener is at all present: I will `postMessage` according to some convention, and, if the listener exists, it will `postMessage` back.

At what point can I be certain that there is no listener? How do I implement the wait?

I tried - on IE11, Chrome and Firefox - the following experiment:

1. `postMessage` *the iframe's window* which posts back immediately on receipt of message
2. `postMessage` *one's own window* as a means to dispatch future points in event processing

Here's the code for these steps:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('hello', '*');
window.postMessage('schedule', '*')
```

The iframe's response code is this:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    window.top.postMessage('echo ' + event.data, '*');
}, false);
```

And the parent window's listener itself is this:

```
var n = 0;
window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
    if (n > 4) return;
    console.info(event.data);
    window.postMessage('(repeat of ' + event.data + ' #' + n + ')', '*')
    n++;
}, false);
```

In words, I continuously re-dispatch events in order to have logging about the nature of the queue.

On IE11, Chrome and Firefox this gives (repeatedly):

```
schedule <-- shouldn't make the mistake to believe there's no listener yet!
echo hello
(repeat of schedule #0)
(repeat of echo hello #1)
(repeat of (repeat of schedule #0) #2)
```

I can "guess" why this is: The browser has one message queue and puts the the first two messages ("hello" and then "schedule") in. Those will both be processed before any that will be scheduled later. In particular, the iframe's answer will be scheduled on processing the "hello" message, which will then be processed after the "schedule" message.

So, to know for sure whether there is a listener, one has to post a "schedule" message on one's own window, and then another "repeat of schedule #0" message from the processing on that event.

Only if in the processing of this indirect "repeat of schedule #0" message there is still no word from the iframe, we can be sure that there is no listener.

Whew, that's a complicated solution for such a simple problem.

My question is: Is there any kind of guarantee that browsers have one common message queue so that events are really dispatched in this manner?

And of course, is there an easier way that is still reliable? (Don't even think about timers!)